# Prove that a $(n-1)$-manifold $M$ disconnects the euclidean space into two connected part

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-topology, connectedness

**Definition**

A convex curve/surface is a simple curve/surface in the Euclidean plane/space which lies completely on one side of each and every one of its tangent lines/planes.

So more generally we give the following definition

**Definition**

A $(n-1)$-manifold of the $n$-dimensional euclidean space is convex if it lies completely on one side of each and every one of its tangent space.

So with the previous definition I ask to me  if a $(n-1)$-manifold $M$ disconnects the euclidean space into two connected part. First of all I observed that the intersection $U$ of the positive tangent spaces is not empty because $M$ is there contained trivially and thus being any positive tangent space connected surely $U$ is even connected so that the statement follows showing that the complement of $U$ is connected too but unfortunately I do not be able to do it and thus I ask to prove it. Moreover is my argument about the connectdness of $U$ correct? So could someone help me?

Comment: I don’t know that I understand everything you say in your argument, but you will need something more from your submanifold in general. For example the open interval (0,1), thought of as a subspace of the plane, does not separate. If that is not convex enough, turn it into an open semicircle. Maybe if $M$ is properly embedded?

Comment: In that case the intersection of the tangent lines is just the not-negative plane given by the equation $$y\ge 0$$ as you can verify and clearly the plane is the disjoint union of the negative and not-negative semiplanes, right?

Comment: I’m just pointing out that the examples I gave satisfy your definition of convex but do not separate.

Comment: What means that they do not separate?

Comment: Their complement is connected; they do not disconnect the plane.

Comment: How do you define the "interior" of a convex curve? I thought to define it as the intersection of the tangent spaces and so with respect thi definition the interior of $(0,1)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ is the not-negative semiplane and $\Bbb R^2$ is the disjoint and **connected** union of this semiplane and its complement and thus with respect my definition your counterexample fails. Anyway with respect this definition a point as $(1,5)$ would be an "interior" point of $(0,1)$ and this seems strangerly. So how do you define the "interior" of a convex curve or surface?

Comment: I think you mean a compact manifold (without boudary).

Comment: @PaulFrost To be honest I do not know precisely.

Comment: @PaulFrost My text of Analytic Mechanic gives the definition of convex curved/surface to prove an interesting result about a system of applied parallel vectors that it is useful to prove that a rigid body is in static motion on a plane only if the projection on the plane of the  centroid is in the interior of the its support that it suppose to be a convex curve and so I think it could be a (**finite**) line too that is a compact $1$-manifold with boudary.

Comment: @PaulFrost Anyway by the **proof** of [this](http://www.albertostrumia.it/sites/default/files/images/books/Meccanica/01_capitolo1.pdf) theorem (see page 48 of the document - in Italian, sorry) I argue that it define the "interior" of a convex surface to be the intersection of the tangent spaces.

Comment: @PaulFrost However if you can prove the statement to a compact manifold I will grateful!